# Make a php json file which display first folder and next files in a directory + how to echo file extension

Tags: php, json

```
$dir = "../../";
if(is_dir($dir)){
    if($dh = opendir($dir)){
        while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false){
            if($file != "." and $file != ".."){
                $files_array[] = array('file' => $file);
            } 
        }
    }
    sort($files_array);
    $return_array =array('name_array' => $files_array);
    echo json_encode($return_array);
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
```

How to make it ? There is my source code. I want to know how to sort it + how to echo file extension. Thx :)

Comment: Can you add some more description - what is it doing and what can't you get to work?

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What's the current and desired output?

Comment: It might help to look at the [various array sorting functions in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

Answer (score 0):

1. header must be set before echo
2. stop the cycle after recovering the first file, if you only want the first one. Or if you want the first in alphabetical order, return only the first element of the array to return less data. Check if exist first element of array.
3. set the array empty in case the directory has no files
4. check that the first result is not a directory, if you want a file

Sample:

```php
    header('Content-type: application/json'); # before echo
    $dir = "../../";
    $files_array=[]; # empty array
    if(is_dir($dir)){
        if($dh = opendir($dir)){
            while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false){
                if($file != "." and $file != ".."){
                    if(!is_dir($file)){ # check is not dir
                        $ext = '';
                        if(strpos($file,'.', 1)) {
                            $aExt = explode(".", $file);
                            # select last element for extension
                            $ext = $aExt[count($aExt)-1];
                        }
                        $files_array[] = array('file' => $file, 'ext'=> $ext ); 
                        break; # break while
                    } 
                } 
            }
        }
        # sort($files_array); # sort multiple file
        # $return_array =array('name_array' => (isset($files_array[0]?$files_array[0]:[]))); # return only first element if exist
        $return_array =array('name_array' => $files_array);
        echo json_encode($return_array);
    }
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer, unfortunately I can't make it work :/ what can I do?

Comment: Yes, there was an error
                    `if (!is_dir($file)) {`
and not
                     `if (!is_dir($dir)) {`